# How do I make these HTML characters?  

Tags: html

Dog and cat, WTH? I got these in an email from Reddit, but don't know how they did them. A google search turned up nothing since these characters aren't really searchable.

Comment: Didn't you just make them when you asked this question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the icon can be used anywhere by just copying them but his question is valid how to make these

Comment: I found them searching for "cat dog unicode"......

Comment: Interesting. Time to change name to  ?

Comment: I can't even see them :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this html escapes:

```
&#128049; - cat
&#128054; - dog
```

And all other **unicode** characters you can find [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/miscellaneous-symbols-and-pictographs/).

Comment: Thanks. So it's the browsers that are turning old unicode characters into colorized icons then? Nothing has been added to the unicode character selection?

Answer (score 1):

HTML unicode characters is the thing which you need.

You can get the symbols you want from:

http://unicode-table.com/en/